# Bad Css Selector?

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get a custom 404 page working on my website, however the css is not working.

Css:

```
#404-container{
    text-align: center; 
}

.404-item{
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="404-container">
    <h1 class="404-item">404</h1>
    <h3 class="text-format-italic 404-item">The requested page could not be found</h3>
</div>
```

The firefox console says:
`Selector expected.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aha! Please never start your classes and IDs with numbers. This is best programming practice. You can even never start your variable names with numbers as well.

Change it to something like:

```
#four04 {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly :D I will accept it when stackoverflow lets me (unless a better one comes along, but I don't see how):)

Comment: Stackoverflow won't let me, it wants me to wait... I will mark it as soon as I can.

Comment: Haha yeah. 8 minutes, I guess. I faced that many times as well. xD :D

Comment: Ok, it just let me :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried and run the code and it worked fine in mine.. So i don't really know. try using container404 or something instead of 404-container. I think this link might be useful to you. go through the comments and see if your error is solved:-

http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/web_publishing/f1133.shtml

Comment: That link talks about html comments in css, how is that applicable here? Also: the thing about moving the numbers worked :)

Comment: Ah.. Sorry i thought that you might just see the comments and find out if you have made any of the mistakes those guys made